# ssh from ubuntu into another ubuntu using private key

Tags: 14.04, ssh

I am trying to SSH into to an amazon Linux server (server B) from the current server (server A) which is an ubuntu.

The Server B is accessible via a Private key (ppk) and not a password.

I have already uploaded the Server B private key into Server A.

What is the command that I need to run in Server A in order to SSH into B using the private key?

Comment: I have done a similar task before. But I generated a pair of keys in server A and copied the public key in server B. Is it what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use -i option of ssh to specify your private key

```
ssh -i private_key.ppk user@server
```